# How can this compile?

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

How does the second call to `meow()` compile here?

```
#include <iostream>

struct F {
    struct E {
        using is_it_safe = bool;
    };

    E e;
};

template<typename T, typename = typename T::E::is_it_safe>
const void* meow(T const& t)
{
    return &t;
}

int main() {
    F f;

    meow(f); // meow<F, bool>
    meow(f.e); // meow<F::E, bool> ??
}
```

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/z9Wzb9v8G)

`F::E` doesn't have a nested `E`, so how does the compiler deduce the second template parameter?

Comment: `F::E::E` refers back to `F::E` ([demo](https://onlinegdb.com/leaMHm3zbT))

Comment: @RemyLebeau F::E::E - I'm pretty sure that's an original song.

Answer (score 7):

`E` has an [*injected-class-name*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name), so that `E::E` is itself (`E`).

So `F::E::E::is_it_safe` is `bool`, since `F::E::E` is the `E` class:

```cpp
F::E::E::is_it_safe x;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), bool>);
```